# "Win32Exception: The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present" when deploying Fabric Cluster on Nano Server

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager

I am deploying a Service Fabric Cluster on Nano Server using the secure-cluster-5-node template (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype)

I get the following error:

```
Operation xxx
Tracking xxx
StatusConflict
Provisioning StateFailed
Timestamp‎6‎/‎22‎/‎2017‎ ‎13‎:‎05‎:‎14
Duration6 minutes 11 seconds
TypeMicrosoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets
Resource Id/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/nt1vm
StatusMessage{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
"code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
"message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
"details": [
  {
    "code": "VMExtensionHandlerNonTransientError",
    "message": "Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode' has reported failure for VM Extension 'ServiceFabricNodeVmExt_vmNodeType0Name' with terminal error code '1007' and error message: 'Install failed for plugin (name: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode, version 1.0.0.35). Exception:\nSystem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present\r\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Agent.StateMachine.HandlerStateMachine.InvokeCommand(String command, PluginArtifacts pluginArtifact, String pluginVersion, String pluginFolder, String pluginLogFolder, Int32 processWaitTimeout, PluginEventType startType, PluginEventType endType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Agent.StateMachine.HandlerStateMachine.InstallHandler(PluginArtifacts artifact)'"
  }
]
}
}
```

The settings are using in the ARM template for the os is:

```
"vmImagePublisher": {
  "value": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
},
"vmImageOffer": {
  "value": "WindowsServer"
},
"vmImageSku": {
  "value": "2016-Nano-Server"
},
"vmImageVersion": {
  "value": "latest"
},
```

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, Nano Server is not supported by Service Fabric Cluster. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-anywhere#supported-operating-systems-for-clusters-on-azure).

> **You are able to create clusters on VMs running these operating
>   systems:**
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> Windows Server 2016
>
> Linux Ubuntu 16.04(in public preview)

You also could check it on Azure Portal. `2016-Nano-Server` could not be selected.
[image]